# Pass Ant Parameters as string to mysql query

Tags: mysql, ant, phpmyadmin

I am using the statement below to add a record in my mysql database where each column is of type longtext, but can't seem to get this working, and I get this message "You Have an error in your sql statement

```
    <sql
     driver="${DB_DRIVER}"  
     url="${DB_URL}"
     userid="${DB_USER}"
     password="${DB_PASSWORD}"
     print="yes" 
     classpathref="antclasspath">

     INSERT INTO `book_logs`(`bookName`, `logFile`, `description`) VALUES (${build_log_filename},${build_log_dir},${FAIL_MESSAGE})
    </sql>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following query with quotas :

```
 INSERT INTO `book_logs`(`bookName`, `logFile`, `description`) VALUES ('${build_log_filename}','${build_log_dir}','${FAIL_MESSAGE}')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the ` around the values, too. Else the sql will be invalid:

```
INSERT INTO `book_logs`(`bookName`, `logFile`, `description`) 
VALUES (`${build_log_filename}`,`${build_log_dir}`,`${FAIL_MESSAGE}`)
```